# Table rates -> Free shipping from X € - different taxes

Tags: magento-1, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping, table-rates

Is there a way to set free shipping in tablerates for a Total inkl. Tax? The problem is tablerates are using the subtotal without tax but i need it including tax. Because we use two different taxes, we can´t just calculate the price without tax.

I want to set free-shipping in my tablerates .csv for a Total of 19€ including tax. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add new Condition in Table Rates for Price incl. Tax vs. Destination. In order to do that in `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php` -> `public function getCode` below this line:

```
'package_value' => Mage::helper('shipping')->__('Price vs. Destination'),
```

add this code:

```
'package_value_incl_tax'  => Mage::helper('shipping')->__('Price incl. Tax vs. Destination'),
```

and below this:

```
'package_value' => Mage::helper('shipping')->__('Order Subtotal (and above)'),
```

add this:

```
'package_value_incl_tax'  => Mage::helper('shipping')->__('Order Subtotal incl. Tax (and above)'),
```

This to be able to work you have to add in `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php` -> `public function collectRatesByAddress` below:

```
$request->setPackageValue($address->getBaseSubtotal());
```

this:

```
$request->setPackageValueInclTax($address->getPackageValueInclTax());
```

and in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php` -> `public function requestShippingRates` below:

```
$request->setPackageValue($item ? $item->getBaseRowTotal() : $this->getBaseSubtotal());
```

this:

```
$request->setPackageValueInclTax($item ? $item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax() : $this->getBaseSubtotalInclTax());
```